# How to redirect users to different pages based on their roles in Flask-login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

how can I redirect users to different pages based on their roles in Flask-login? I'm trying to catch the 'flask.ext.login.user_logged_in' signal but I'm not sure how to redirect flask at signal level.

```
def handle_user_logged_in(sender, user):
    for r in user.roles:
        if r.name == 'admin':
            # This line doesn't work because it's not in a 'View'
            return redirect('/admin')

user_logged_in.connect(handle_user_logged_in, app)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss the url_for()

```
def handle_user_logged_in(sender, user):
for r in user.roles:
    if r.name == 'admin':
        return redirect(url_for('admin'))

user_logged_in.connect(handle_user_logged_in, app)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Another way..

This may be helpful. I have been following in the same way without using signals.

```
from flask.ext.login import current_user
```

#### in views.py

```
def not_logged_in():
    return render_to_template('home.html')

def view_fn():
   if not current_user:
      #Anonymous user
      return redirect(url_for('not_logged_in'))
   elif 'admin' in current_user.roles:
      #admin page
   else:
      #default roles redirect
```

#### Note:

make sure you have the proper User models with roles fields
https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#how-it-works

## OR

This function calls for each request.So, if you want to apply common logic for `anonymous user` across all `view` function, you could even follow this way

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = current_user

    if not current_user:
         print "user not logged in"
         #if you return anything from here make sure to skip for login, signup views
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This method will work but it seems to be inefficient. The user checking is done at every request. If this can be done only once it will be great.